# MySQL data types

Tags: sql, mysql, mobile, types

What is the proper data type to store 10 digit mobile Number like `98**********` in MySql?

Comment: I don't think SO is here to answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: you should learn [MySql data types](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-data-types-50.file)

Comment: Sorry, early as possible is not possible anymore.... it is already 11am here. But if you can wait I will answer at 12am later...

Comment: 4 answers to this question how it can be possible. This fellow is just wasting peoples time. He should search net or read book. why so much peoples are answering this question. ;-D

Comment: @dan yes may be you are right. may be they are doing it for reputation.

Comment: You might get this answer from here. I strongly suggest you please learn some basic things about SQL from books and from internet. It will help you in future.

Comment: @dan, @harry, @enam, @naysayers - if you can find a duplicate, please close it and point to the duplicate. Otherwise if your response is "search on Google", do you think Google makes up the answers itself?

Comment: @cyberkiwi This isn't the type of question you even search for, you just read the first chapter of the software manual.

Comment: @Dan Can't remember the last time I read a software manual instead of hitting Google

Comment: @cyberkiwi You can use Google to find the right page of the manual, then read a paragraph, rather than ask a question you know will be covered in said manual. If you put "mysql" at the start of your query, Google's always gonna give you the manual as the first result.

Answer (score 4):

If it is always 10 digits, use char(10) with the UI to enforce the "98" prefix.

To be forward looking, you could use VARCHAR(12) or even VARCHAR(20) since there is absolutely no additional storage, and you will want to enforce the country/area code from the UI in some way anyway (to 10 digits), so having some flexibility at the database layer will be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

There's several possibilities, but without knowing more about your application, it'll be hard to make good recommendations. Details on the data types that are probably closest: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-types.html

Answer (score 0):

`char(10)` or equivalent

That is, fixed length character.

I'd also add a check constraint to ensure that you store only:

- values starting "98"
- all numbers

Answer (score 0):

It's generally best to store this as a varchar. The advantage of storing it as string data is that numeric datatypes will strip off leading zeros, remove spaces, etc.

Another approach is to store the phone number in 3 separate fields - country code, area code, and number (possibly have an extension field as well). This gives a lot of flexibility for the future. Naturally, you will want to have methods (either a database function, or an application function) which can convert this data into a format suitable for viewing.

In pseudocode:

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumber
   countryCode char(2),
   areaCode char(5),
   number   varchar(6),
   extension varchar(6)
```